# How to get Ansible use fail module with arrays?

Tags: arrays, debugging, ansible

It looks like Ansible can use the debug module with arrays to output multiple lines

```
- name: debug something
  debug:
    msg:
      - "y"
      - "x"
```

Output:

```
TASK [debug something] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "y", 
        "x"
    ]
}
```

How to get the same behavior with "-fail"?

```
TASK [Exit on failure] **********************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": ["y", "x"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently not supported by Ansible up to version 2.4.2.